# Promql get percentage between two metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I want to get percentage between two metrics

```
metrics_value_under_10{host=~"$host"} 20
metrics_value_upper_10{host=~"$host"} 2
```

percentage for metrics_value_under_10 :

```
(20/22)*100=90,9 %
```

so on promql request

```
((sum by (host) (increase(metrics_value_under_10{host=~"$host"}[30s]))) / (sum by (host) (increase(metrics_value_under_10{host=~"$host"}[30s])) + sum by (host) (increase(metrics_value_upper_10{host=~"$host"}[30s]))))*100
```

But I don't get the percentage that I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following PromQL:

```
100 * metrics_value_under_10{host=~"$host"} / ( metrics_value_under_10{host=~"$host"} + metrics_value_upper_10{host=~"$host"} )
```